# Angular cli and javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'll explain my situation.

I have a external javascript file that has a function like:

```
searchForSomething(id, callbackFunction);
```

That method 'searchForSomething' is async and the return is call the callbackFunction.
In my component.ts I have:

```
declare function searchForSomething(id, callbackFunction): any;
...
message: string;
id: number;
...
next(){
  searchForSomething(this.id, this.print);
}

print(result: string) {
  this.message = result;
  console.log(result);
}
...
```

ERROR:
Uncaught ReferenceError: 'message' is not defined

But neither 'this' is defined. My code works using this test:

```
next(){
  //searchForSomething(this.id, this.print);
  this.print('result as a mock.');
}
```

I guess that I have a context or scope problem here.
I got that when my ts method is called by external javascript, I lost angular references.

What's the rigth way to use call back function into ts? Or I need to review my javascript method to remove 'function' parameter? But it is async, so I can't just remove the callbackFunction, put a return and wait for a result.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This issue has noting to do with Angular or TS. I can be demonstrated in javascript (es6 at least) https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-angular-cli-and-javascript-callback-function https://jsbin.com/cenexacifi/2/edit?js,console

Comment: es5 demonstration of the problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-angular-cli-and-javascript-callback-function-es5

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue about scope. When you pass callback function, the function loses its scope.

So, you can convert `print` to arrow function to make the function's scope where it is defined:

```
print = (result: string) => {
  this.message = result;
  console.log(result);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Also you can use `.bind(this)` to assign the scope manually if you don't want to use arrow functions.

```
next(){
  searchForSomething(this.id, this.print.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: You can read more on this issue here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html Section: "this and arrow functions"

Comment: @Robert Thanks for extending the answer.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz thanks, That works! And I undertood a bit more about Javascript and Angular.
I used the bind solution.

Comment: Actually the arrow functions are more useful in this context because they keep scope themselves where they are defined. Glad to help btw :)